# Importing String tabel to the another activity

Tags: java, android

I want to import string tabel to the another activity. (That activities are launched from main activity).

Code for activity from I want import:

```
public class LineGraph{
        Context applicationContext;
        Boolean Buttons;
        Boolean Legend;
        Boolean Grid;
        public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            Buttons = prefs.getBoolean("view", true);
            Legend = prefs.getBoolean("legend", true);
            Grid = prefs.getBoolean("Grid", false);
            // Our first data
            int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
            int[] y =  { 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; // y values!
            TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1"); 
            for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            {
                series.add(x[i], y[i]);
            }

            // Our second data
            int[] x2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
            int[] y2 =  { 145, 123, 111, 100, 89, 77, 57, 45, 34, 30}; // y values!
            TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries("Line2"); 
            for( int i = 0; i < x2.length; i++)
            {
                series2.add(x2[i], y2[i]);
            }

            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            dataset.addSeries(series2);

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
            mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
            if (Buttons==true){
            mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);}
            else{
            mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false); 
            }
            if (Legend==true){
                mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
            }else{
                mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
            }
            if (Grid==true){
                mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
            }else{
                mRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
            }
            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 1
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 2
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

            // Customization time for line 1!
            renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
            renderer.setFillPoints(true);
            // Customization time for line 2!
            renderer2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
            renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
            return intent;

        }

    }
```

And code for activity to I want import

```
package graph.activity;
public class GraphLoading extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    }
}
```

I want to import this:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

From `LineGraph` class to `GraphLoading` Class

Comment: It is spelled "activity" (2 x 'i') not "activty", and by "tabel" DYM "table"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intent.putExtra("SomeKey",x)` and in `onCreate` `getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("SomeKey")`:

```
package graph.activity;
public class GraphLoading extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        int[] x = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("SomeKey");
    }
}
```

Comment: How? The GraphLoading are not launched before LineGraph class only when the activity is next i can do this